# Sleep stages and rythm

Tags: sleep

I would like to get a rough understanding of sleep stages and their rythm, especially in relation to my experiences with sleep.
Disclaimer: I hope to get explanations to my experiences with this post. I do not seek medical advice here, for this i consulted a medical professional. But they couldn't give me satisfying explanations.

If i sleep 6 hours (+- 30 min) i have an easy time getting out of bed, feel well rested and energetic throughout my day. 6 hours has been my average for the past half year or so.
If i sleep more (e.g. 8 hours) i experience the opposite. I have to drag my self out of bed and feel tired for hours to come. I also don't "fully recover" to the point i feel like with 6 hours of sleep. In the past i used to have an 8 hour schedule. But i was aware of the 6 hour behavior and abused it on days i needed an energy boost.
If i sleep until i wake up by my self (10-12 hours usually) i do feel well rested, but have a slower start in the day than with 6 hours. I usually try to avoid sleeping in this long.

From what i understood this experience is related to the sleep stage i am in when i wake and 6 hours seems to hit the "sweet spot" for me. Altho i don't know any other span that would result in the same experience. So im asking my self the following questions

1. Which sleep stages are there and how do they influence you when you wake during them?
2. Are there ways to "schedule" these stages to shift my 6 hour cycle to 8 hours?

Sorry if this post isn't in the right place here. Let me know and i will remove it.

Comment: The background information you give and your second question place this post in the "medical advice" category, even though that may not have been the intent. If you remove all that, it boils down to a very broad question that shows no evidence of research, something this site strongly advises in order to get an answer. Sleep is complicated; you can start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep). You can change your sleep pattern for the better, but you need a good sleep specialist's help.

Comment: I think there are some good questions in there but as anongoodnurse says you'll need to separate them from medical advice and also separate them from "tutorial":: Stack Exchange is for specific questions with specific answers, there are entire books written about sleep stages and their rhythms. It would be better to start reading about this on your own (Wikipedia is a decent starting place) and then as you come across things that are unclear you can ask questions here about those.